# Excel: Breaking down employees by departments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out excel by breaking down my team at work based on their departments and if they're present.

I would like a formula that would automatically list them under their department if they're present on my first sheet.

••••••••••A••••••••••••••••••••••••B

Human Resources•••••••Operations

••••••John Doe•••••••••••••Joe Snuffy

•••••••••Etc.••••••••••••••••••••••Etc.

The second sheet will have a list of my team members and their respected department, as well as if they're present.

Team Member•••••Present•••••••Department

••••John Doe•••••••••••Y•••••••Human Resources

My formula on sheet1 in A3 has been =IF(sheet2!C2="Human Resources" & sheet2!B2="Y", sheet2!A2)

It has been returning FALSE.

I would like the formula to scan the column of team members that are present and automatically put them under their departments, without any blank cells inbetween them.

Comment: I don't really know how your source data looks like. Anyway, the IF formula you use does not check what you want. Now you are checking if sheet2!C2 is equal to concatenation of "Human Resources" and sheet2!B2. Then the resulting TRUE or FALSE is compared to "Y" which is always FALSE. In other words your formula always evaluates to FALSE, no matter the variables. Use function "and()" to perform logical "and".

Comment: Figured it out. I Italy forgot about AND(). Thank you so much!